# Disable our add-in in unsupported versions of Office

Tags: office-js

Is it possible to disable our add-in in unsupported versions/build of Office. So users are not able to search for the add-in in the Store listing in unsupported versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with the **Requirements** element in the add-in's manifest. See this article for details: [Specify Office hosts and API requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).

Comment: Thank you Rick - this is useful link :)